# Executing Pre-steps with karate

Tags: karate, ibm-api-management

In my current middleware integration project, We are using WSO2 API manager tool to manage the API life-cycle. 
In test level to access an API I have to create an application and subscribe to the specific API. This can achieved by making a number of rest API requests. I decided to use karate to make these api requests too. 
So that part is the pre-steps for my karate test-suite (Or whatever karate tests I execute).

Is there a way to lock down these steps to run before whatever the karate tests I will be executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, look for `karate.callSingle()`: https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

```
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:demo/headers/common-noheaders.feature', config);
```